# Higher accuracy for tanh function in Tensorflow as compare to numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, floating-accuracy

I can't figure out why tanh calculation has higher accuracy in tensorflow-2.2.0 as compare to numpy. Please have a look at example below.

[image: tanh(0.963801444)]

I appreciate your time and reply.

Thanks,

Comment: What makes you think the Tensorflow result is the more accurate one?

Answer (score 1):

The NumPy result is more accurate.  For comparision, Wolfram Alpha gives the result 0.745967716740428007413668705771485305302298638189343426746...

NumPy uses 64 bit floating point (i.e. [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) by default, while tensorflow uses 32 bit floating point (i.e. [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)).

Comment: Re “Tensorflow uses 32 bit floating point”: This alone does not explain the result. Converting .963801444 to IEEE-754 binary 32 and calculating tanh should yield 0.74596774578094482421875, not .7459678053855896. It is only an ULP difference, but it suggests Tensorflow’s `tanh` is inaccurate beyond what is necessitated by the format.